# Magento 2.4: How to add the locale for a website using config.php?

Tags: magento2.4, multi-website, production-mode, locale, locale-translation

Our Magento website is hosted on Commerce cloud and I have created the multi website but since the commerce cloud is in production mode, I'm not able to update the locale using admin settings.

I get to know that we can add the locale via config.php but I'm not sure how to add it.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

On your local environment set the wanted locale. Then run bin/magento app:config:dump. This will dump all your config in your config.php. Then you can see how your locale is going to be set in the config.php. Then you can revert the file and only leave the config needed in your config.php. Once it is done you will have to run bin/magento app:config:import.

Note that everyhing that you have in your config.php wont be editable in the admin.